# What are some important properties for classification of signals? (P300 speller project)

Tags: signal, signal-processing

I'm trying to detect p300 in signals by using classification methods. each signals is 700 ms (sampling rate : fs=1000) long and p300 should happen somewhere between 200-400 ms. Signals are detected from 64 different channels.
The properties I have used so far are:

In time domain:

- variance
- (mean in 200:400 ms)- (mean in elsewhere)
- correlation of different channels
- the time when the signal is at its maximum amount
- mean of the whole signal
- (maximum in 200:400)-(maximum elsewhere)
- the number of data with a value between 7 and 8, 6 and 8, 5 and 8

In frequency domain:

- mean frequency
- mode frequency
- median frequency

What other properties do you suggest I use ?

The blue signal in these pictures contains p300, and the other doesn't:[image: sample 1]
[image: sample 2]

Comment: What is a "p300 speller" and how can it be detected?

Comment: @JRE P300 is a brain signal that appears when your brain is somehow stimulated. It happen 200 to 400 ms after the stimulation. In this project , a table of characters is shown to a person and the person has a certain character in mind. Each time a column or row is lightened up. If the row/column contains that specific character, then the person's brain is stimulated and the signal contains p300. I have uploaded two examples. I have data for signals without p300 and with p300. My job is to use properties of these data for machine learning.